# VS2010 Form being cropped at run time on Laptop

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installshield, splash-screen, screen-resolution, autosize

Hi I have developed a VS2010 application in Windows 7. I am also using InstallShield Premier to create an Setup.exe/MSI as usual.

The problem is that my splash screen is being cropped on the right hand side when I install on to a laptop which has a screen resolution of 1366 x 768. 
(On a desktop of 1900 x 1080 it is fine, both the forms are visible).

My main form is of size 1330 x 848 and appears ok albeit snug.
The Splash screen form is only of size 562 x 398 so this should in theory fit well easy but this form is being cropped by say 25% on the right. So only 75% of the Splash screen is visible missing out the "Skip" button on the right.
This form does have a progress bar using a timer and a centre logo, can't think why this would have any bearing.

I am aware if the Form Autuosize attribute, Autuosize to True and have tried looking in the Installshield parameters to no avail.

I have recently added a background (and stretch to fill) to both Forms which may have some bearing on the matter but doubt it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm, it is Math.Pi bigger than it should be.  A number that crops up everywhere in nature.  But not here, we can't see your code.

Comment: Which code would you like to see the Form code for the splash screen right ? or both. It is quite extensive coding. I am no sure it would help as the form seems to be standard. I will try and create a new application and create a spalsh screen only and try and isolate the problem. If my new splash screen form work then I know its something peripheral to the application. I will also try and remove the bacground image in case this is the cause. Thxs ps. Like the Month.Pi :)

Answer (score 0):

have you set your splash screen form startposition to centerscreen in properties window? maybe you mess with it and it now starts at the right side.

since you created it in a higher resolution display and run it in a lower resolution will likely cropped. use the autosize from the properties window.

Comment: Yes, indeed that was my first place to look. The problem is that the screen position is set to "Centre" but it is the size of the splash screen that is the problem. It's as if the right hand side of the Form has literally been sliced off vertically. I will also try and remove the background maybe this is inadvertently having an effect. Thxs